# Load images from angulajs ng-repeat as needed

Tags: angularjs, base64, lazy-loading

I need to load images from array in angularjs just as needed, meaning that I want the image be load only when scrolling to this image..
The sources of the images are base64.
I can load the images but I don't know how to do it lazy loading.
my html:

```
 <table ng-if="This_Page.Images_Src" class="table">
    <tr >
      <td ng-repeat="One_Entry in This_Page.Images_Src track by $index" ng-init="index = $index">
          <img data-ng-src="{{One_Entry}}"   width="240" height="152">
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

my js:

```
 $scope.Handle_Doc_Images_Arrival = function(data){

          if ((typeof data                != "undefined") &&
              (       data                != ""         ) &&
              (typeof data.Server_Status  != ""         ) &&
              (       data.Server_Status  == 200        )    ) {

            var l_Result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) ;

            if(typeof l_Result.Server_Response.Result_Code !== "undefined" &&
                      l_Result.Server_Response.Result_Code ==  "0"            ) {

                $scope.This_Page.Doc_Images = [] ;
                $scope.This_Page.Images_Src = [] ;

                $scope.This_Page.Doc_Images = l_Result.Server_Response.Result_Data.Doc_Images ;

                for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.This_Page.Doc_Images.length ; i++){
                    $scope.This_Page.Images_Src.push($scope.This_Page.Doc_Images[i].Image) ;
                }

            }
            else {
                $rootScope.Show_Error_Message('Attempt to get Doc Images failed : ' + l_Result.Server_Response.Result_Message) ;
                return ;
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: would you mind telling me if my answer worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R2pt9vJk6ZloaQcUJHBY?p=preview)

```
<img style="width: auto;" my-lazy-src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">
```

The section of code has been taken from [this article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2498-lazy-loading-image-with-angularjs.htm)